# creating number patterns in java(continued)

Tags: java, design-patterns

I need to create these patterns in java according to however many lines the user enters:

1
12
123
1234
12345

54321
4321
321
21
1

12345
1234
123
12
1

I can do the first two but I cannot do the third.  I also need a space between each number.  Please help!

Here is the code I used for the first:

public static void displayPatternI (int lines) {

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++){
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            System.out.print (j + " " );
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
this is the code for the second pattern:

for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++){
    for (int j = lines + 1 - i; j > 0; j--)
           System.out.print (j + " ");
             System.out.println();

I have tried modifying the first code extensively but I cannot get the third pattern...

Comment: What is your question? Where are your attempts for the others and what in part of your code has you stuck?

Comment: You could use recursion to do it, instead of nesting loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your first for loop to decrement instead of increment

```
for (int i = lines; i > 0; i--) {
```

instead of

```
for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++){
```

Comment: Thank you man!  I see how you did that. I dont know why I didnt see this before...Thanks again!